# How to tell the maximum speed of copying a file using Finder or cp or rsync?

Tags: macos, finder, ssd, catalina, rsync

I got a Samsung T7 SSD drive knowing that it can handle 1GB/s read or write, but if I used

```
rsync -a --progress --stats --human-readable file1.m4v /Volumes/T7/file1.m4v
```

to tell the speed of copying a file, it only can go up to 180MB/s or at most 220MB/s (and `cp` feels slow as well).  But if I open up two Finder windows and drag and drop the file over, it really feels like 5 seconds to copy a 5GB iTunes movie file. (I then used a stopwatch to find out copying 16.5GB needed about 19 seconds).

(I think why the UI drag and drop can copy so much faster is due to `rsync` or `cp` using one processor core, and it is limited to one core's speed.)

So if I use the UI's drag and drop way of copying, is there a way to tell the copy speed? Or alternatively, if I use any command in Bash, can it copy a file at the maximum speed of the SSD and be able to tell the speed?

Comment: Disk performance is tricky to measure, considering all the caching etc which is involved. Which Mac model do you use? Can you run `time dd bs=$((64*1024)) count=XX if=/dev/zero of=/Volumes/T7/test.dump` with various values for `XX` (e.g, 1, 16, 32768) and add the terminal output to the question?

Comment: @NimeshNeema even if that question you mentioned answered why `cp` is slower, it doesn't answer the part about "able to tell the copy speed" using Finder or Bash

Comment: The T7 SSD has two different "caches": DRAM & SLC (no real cache but fast flash). SLC: 500 GB model: 22 GB, 1 TB model: 42 GB and 2 TB: 78 GB - the rest is TLC. I expect  the DRAM to be 64 MB (but I can't find specs). The low values of XX of nohillside's `dd` command simply write to DRAM cache. Example writing 16 MB to a 8 TB HDD: 1.77 GB/s (which is far beyond the normal write speed of 120-180 MB/S). So use larger XX values!

Comment: Please don't ask several questions at once. If the "how can I tell the speed of copying" part is important, it's better to ask a separate question for it.

Comment: @nohillside so I changed the question to only ask one thing